# Refresh values in a database

Tags: php, database

I am really new to database management. I installed wamp and have set up a database in phpmyadmin. Now I need to refresh the value of a particular row which contains some data. How do I do this. Are there any good tutorials for doing this available on the net. Can you please point me in the right direction as I don't know what to do now.

Comment: refresh the value? can u explain ?wat have u tried?

Comment: How did you learn how to insert without the same source mentioning other commands?  Odd...  Anyway, look into any basic MySQL (or whatever RDBMS) tutorials.  (Or do you literally want to do it from within PMA? Because if so, ignore this comment.)

Comment: do page refresh..phpmyadmin fetch new data

Answer (score 1):

It's called "UPDATE".

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET field_name = new_value");
```

If you add a condition to the end, you can decide which record get's updated.. Assuming you have an "id" field (which is unique to each record), you could change the record with ID 50 by appending:

```
where id = 50
```

to the query.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you are referring to the visual thing more than what is happening on the background. If you hit the button, lets say, update, the page will go to the server and come back with the new, updated results of what you are trying to update. Before digging into using complicated techniques to make this happen nicely, try to understand the page lifecycle. Then start applying javascript(and AJAX) if you want to make this happen nicely. Hope this helps,